# How effective to override the default Threadpool executor for Spring webflux project?

Tags: spring-webflux

I am new to Spring-Webflux.

I am running the below sample project in a 2 - core processor. My RESTful api will call to an external api and the external api response is less than 500ms.

When i using jMeter for load testing, can't achieve more than 15 TPS.

Am i missing something or anything wrong with the below design?

How effective it's to override the default Threadpool executor in Webflux project?

Thank you in advance.

---

**Controller**

```
public class LookupController {

    @Autowired
    private LookupService lookupService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/findOrder")
    public Mono findOrder(@RequestBody InputBean inputBean) {

        return lookupService.findOrder(inputBean)
                .map(resp -> ResponseEntity.ok(resp))
                .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
}
```

---

**Service**

```
@Service
public class LookupService {

    @Autowired
    private RestWorker restWorker;

    public Mono findOrder(InputBean inputBean) {
        ..//Basic Validation
        ApiBean apiBean = restWorker.buildApiBean(inputBean);
        Mono responseStr = restWorker.callApi(apiBean);
        return responseStr.flatMap(resp -> {
            //Business Logic
            //Process the api response and create the corresponding Controller Response
            return Mono.just(controllerResponse);
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Helper**

```
@Component
public class RestWorker {

    private Webclient webClient = null;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initWorker() {
        webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(httpUrl)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_CHARSET, "UTF-8")
                .build();
    }

    public ApiBean buildApiBean(InputBean inputBean) {
    // Create ApiBean based on the input bean + config values
    ....
        return apiBean;
    }

    public Mono callApi(ApiBean apiBean) {
        Mono responseMonoStr = null;
        try {
            responseMonoStr = webClient.post()
                    .uri(url_tibco)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(reqDoc))
                    .exchange()
                    .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(socketReadTimeout))
                    .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "Status Code : " + clientResponse.statusCode());
                        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
                    });
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            return Mono.just("");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

It is not, as Spring WebFlux is not using a Threadpool executor to dispatch web requests. It is rather using other server resources, like event loops (for Netty). For more information on that, you can check [the Spring Boot reference documentation on reactive server resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-reactive-server-resources) and more importantly learn about [the concurrency model in Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-concurrency-model).

Comment: Thank you so much. But, why am i getting low TPS? Is my design flaw or how can i efficiently handle the parallel request? Please share your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

Brian Clozel,

Thank you so much. Non-blocking api is working based on event loop with small number of threads. But, when am sending some parallel requests it opens 2 different threads like reactor-http-nio-2, reactor-http-nio-3..

Why it opening different threads on each parallel request?